# Getting error in xcode while build - PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, compiler-errors

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clic in menu Product -> Clean Build Folder and when it finish, Product -> Build and test again

Answer (score -1):

1. Clean Build Folder like Andreas mentioned

(if it doesn't solve the problem ->)

2. Delete Derive Data